# How to use post inside select of autocomplete jquery

Tags: jquery, post, autocomplete

i'm using autocomplete from jquery... and i have this:

```
$('#name_search').autocomplete({
            source: "search/name.php",
            open: function(){
                $(this).autocomplete('widget').css('z-index', 1000);
                    return false;
            },
            select:function(event, ui){
                $(this).val(ui.item.nome+" - "+ui.item.cognome);
                fillAnagrafica(ui);
                var id = ui.item.id;
                $.post("tabella.php",id:id,
                   function(msg){

                      $('#tabella').html(msg);
                      $('#tabella').show();
                   }
                );
                return false;
            }
            }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ){
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.nome + "<br>" + item.cognome + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
            };
```

My problem is that if i remove the post code:

```
$.post("tabella.php",id:id,
                       function(msg){

                          $('#tabella').html(msg);
                          $('#tabella').show();
                       }
                    );
```

autocomplete works good.. if i put post code.. autocomplete doesn't show me text searched.. what could be the problem? can someone help me pls? thanks!

Comment: Do you get any error at all in your JavaScript console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the data argument of $.post

```
  $.post("tabella.php",id:id,
```

Should be

```
 $.post("tabella.php",{id:id},
```

You didn't not encapsulate your data object in curly braces.

Use a browser console to check errors. A console like Firebug would have pointed out the syntax error and pointed you right at it